# Windows Phone: View shifts up when textbox gets focus

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

WP8 : Whenever a texbox comes into focus, the corresponding view of the page shifts up by a margin. Due to which the heading of the page gets cut. I have found a solution to this [problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075273/prevent-screen-scrolling-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown-in-wp7)  , but it doesn't help. Does not work on WP8. Any solutions are appreciated.

Comment: There is no selected answer on there. Which one did you try? All of them? One of them? What didn't work about it? Where is your code?

Comment: what u already tried? but don't want that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable that shift by changing `RenderTransform` back to zero:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.RootFrame.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can disable shift using the `RenderTransform` back to zero as @Ku6opr mentioned. But the real question is would it really do what you want. Noone likes to type if I can not see what I'm typing, this is the reason behind shifting the view upward. 
If you really want to prevent shifting **redesigning the view for a smaller space** will be a much better option. Only disabling the shift somehow wouldn't help much.